# Composer update - RuntimeException

Tags: composer-php

After installing Composer I try to do a `composer update` which tells me this:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
The process has been signaled with signal "11".
```

I'm running OSX 10.6.8 (old, I know). What causes this error?

`composer self-update` ran just fine.

Comment: Does `composer diag` show any significant surprise? How much memory is allowed for PHP on the command line? `php -i | grep memory_limit`

Comment: diag gives me the same error. Memory limit according to your command is 32MB. Added some more info about php. Does that help?

Comment: 32 MB as memory limit is way too low. Composer needs as much as 2 GB when running (at least you should be able to reserve that much memory, usually it goes up to 1 GB in regular use cases). This also means you must have at least that much physical memory installed on the machine - if Composer has to use swapping, it will take hours or days to complete. You could run with the `--profile` cli switch to see memory and runtime usage. Like `composer diag --profile`. But this would only use about 5 MB of memory, so memory isn't the cause for your error.

Comment: What memory limit is this, the php one? As set in the ini file? I have 4GB available on my machine. composer --profile tells me [6.1MB/0.02s] Memory usage: 6.07MB (peak: 6.16MB), time: 0.02s. composer diag --profile gives me the same RuntimeException. All I want to do is install Laravel, jeezus ...

Comment: do you have a `composer.json`? what's inside ?

Answer (score 3):

[signal 11 is a segmentation fault](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm). I guess there is a problem with your version of php.

can you show us the output of `php --version` ? and can you upgrade it if it's not the latest version ?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay in responding. According to your command I'm running PHP 5.4.4. Which php says the same, pointing to my MAMP's php installation. Not sure if I should upgrade my Mac's php or the MAMP installation?

Comment: not sure if it's related, but PHP 5.4.4 is indeed an old version (released on 06 Jun 2012), I suggest you to upgrade to PHP 5.6 because 5.4 is in security-fix only, and PHP 5.5 will soon be (http://php.net/supported-versions.php). Unfortunatly I don't know about installing/upgrading php on OSX, I guess upgrading MAMP should be enough

Answer (score 1):

I had `The process has been signaled with signal "6".` error and I had to run below commands:

```
$brew upgrade subversion
$brew link --overwrite subversion
```

and the issue went! :)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
brew upgrade subversion
brew link --overwrite subversion
```

The above commands solves errors related to Symphony when running

```
composer global update
```